# php mysql compare 2 tables and delete non matching BUT table2 id using REPLACE(id, 'junk' ') AS id

Tags: mysql, replace, inner-join

I have 2 tables

table1 has id column which is just an auto increment number
table2 has id column which is the same but begins with "vt_" then the number

I need to Delete any row on table2 where the table2.id doesn't match the table1.id BUT I'm stuck because I need to replace the "vt_" before I can compare the 2 numbers.

I know I can do it in a SELECT, like this "SELECT REPLACE(table2.id,'vts_','') AS table2_id"

I can't get it to work, my last attempt was like this:

```
$sql = @mysql_query("DELETE 
                           voting
                        FROM 
                            voting
                        INNER JOIN vouchers
                        ON REPLACE(voting.item,'vts_','') = vouchers.id");
```

Comment: How this query doesn't work? also try to post some sample data of these two tables.

Comment: Did you instead try `CONCAT( 'vts_', vouchers.id )`

Comment: [The query you posted should work fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92bbe/1)

Comment: Argh, I made a mistake and only noticed it when you guys posted. It's actually "vt_" but in my code I wrote "vts_" so it did work indeed.
But how do I get it to delete the items that do not match? the code current deletes the matching items... which is a start I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` here

```
DELETE voting
FROM voting LEFT JOIN vouchers
      ON REPLACE(voting.item,'vts_','') = vouchers.id
WHERE  vouchers.id IS NULL
```